# OData V3: how to query derived type when it is stored in a parent table?

Tags: c#, odata

I have the following class structure:

```
abstract class Person {}
class Employee : Person {}
class Customer : Person {}
```

I use some ORMapper (XPO in my case) to store the data in the database in that way the Employee and Customer types are stored in the base "Person" database table.

Then I create an OData V3 web service by using DevExpress Odata provider from DevExpress (and they state that it provides full odata-v3 functionality). So probably it is only the OData related issue.

Now as my derived types are stored in the parent table, in the odata web service project the corresponding types are not autogenerated. So I am unable to query them by using "isof" function (or I am missing something):

http://localhost:51451/ODataService1.svc/Person?$filter=isof('ODataService1.TestOdata.Employee')&$format=json

How should I query only the objects of the selected derived type (e.g. Employee) if it is stored in the parent table?

Any clues that might help a little?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try:..........
  http://localhost:51451/ODataService1.svc/Person/ODataService1.TestOdata.Employee

Comment: Thanks, but then I get "The request URI is not valid. Since the segment 'Person' refers to a collection, this must be the last segment in the request URI. All intermediate segments must refer to a single resource." - the reason I think is that Employee class wasn't autogenerated in my odata project.